# push message Phonegap

Tags: cordova, push-notification

I work on a phonegap application and I'd like to add a push message.

I read a lots of docs but I can't find a push system for phonegap.
I find information about google cloud messaging and a push system for Iphon, but I can't find a solution for both application type.

Is there a solution

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen the GenericPush PhoneGap plugin? More info here: https://build.phonegap.com/blog/introducing-genericpush-plugin